# Questions about RSA padding algorithm

Tags: javascript, security, encryption, rsa

So I have this JavaScript encrypted library which I will be using for a chrome extension that encrypts text strings in RSA then sends it to my server, However I noticed that it uses PKCS#1 (type 2) padding to pad the data.

I just wanted to know if this padding algorithmic is considered secure enough for RSA encrypting text and sending over an unencrypted HTTP connection.

Here is the function that performs the padding:

```
    // PKCS#1 (type 2, random) pad input string s to n bytes, and return a bigint
    function pkcs1pad2(s,n) {
      if(n < s.length + 11) {
        alert("Message too long for RSA");
        return null;
      }
      var ba = new Array();
      var i = s.length - 1;
      while(i >= 0 && n > 0) {ba[--n] = s.charCodeAt(i--);};
      ba[--n] = 0;
      var rng = new SecureRandom();
      var x = new Array();
      while(n > 2) { // random non-zero pad
        x[0] = 0;
        while(x[0] == 0) rng.nextBytes(x);
        ba[--n] = x[0];
      }
      ba[--n] = 2;
      ba[--n] = 0;
      return new BigInteger(ba);
    }
```

How secure is this algorithm, and does it matter much about the padding used in RSA as long as the key is large in size (4096 bit in this case)?

Is this padding considered PKCS#1 1.5?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it looks like PKCS#1 padding. What do you want to hear about it's 'security'? Yes, it is secure. And it is still used in PKI. However you can use OAEP if you doubt about security. However, most often the problem is not on algorithm's side.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just wanted to know if this padding had any weaknesses that it would make it easy for an attacker to decrypt it somehow, I know it's all about how motivated the attacker is and who intercepts the data. I also know the odds of it being intercepted are probably pretty small anyway, and I also know RSA is secure with a 4096bit key. I just wasn't exactly sure if PKCS#1 had weaknesses. I would use OAEP if it were available in Javascript, but PKCS#1 would probably work fine for what I need. What kind of padding does places like facebook use for the key exchange?

Comment: Facebook doesn't use any specific algorithm for key exchange, it's security is based on TLS/SSL, and TLS/SSL uses Diffie-Hellman key exchange.

Comment: You can use forge if you want OAEP in JS: https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge#rsa